# Get sibling td values based on all checked checkboxes in a datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, datatable

```
$('#save-board-assignees').click(function ()
{
    $('#board_assignee_table_wrapper input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(i, td_e)
    {
        console.log('Found checked checkbox');
        var assignee_id = 0;
        var team_id = 0;
        var assignee_holder = [];

        assignee_id = $(this).closest('td').next().attr('id');
        assignee_name = $(this).closest('td').next().html();
        team_id = $(this).closest('td').next().next().attr('id');

        console.log('Assignee name: ' + assignee_name);
        console.log('Team id: ' + team_id);
        console.log('Assignee id: ' + assignee_id);

        assignee_holder.push(assignee_id, assignee_name);
        board_assignees.push(assignee_holder);
    });
}
```

This code only gets the values of the sibling `<td>` (Assignee name, team id, assignee id) of the checked checkbox on the ***page selected***. It doesn't pick up the checked checkboxes in the other pages of the `DataTable`.

Here's a sample snippet of the table structure:
https://jsfiddle.net/30u4knrs/

Comment: @KScandrett will this be okay? https://jsfiddle.net/30u4knrs/1/

Comment: Are you using http://datatables.net/?

Comment: @KScandrett yes yes

Comment: @KScandrett thanks, i'll give the solution there a try

Comment: Posted a better solution than the link I provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.$()` (https://datatables.net/reference/api/%24()) to access all table elements (not just those currently visible):

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

table
   .$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')
   .each(function(i, td_e) { ...
```

Comment: Didn't think it would be so simple. Thanks!